# Test Doctrine ODM respository with phpunit in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, mocking, phpunit, doctrine-odm

I want to test this simple query:

```
public function findArticlesByUsers($ids) {

    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb
            ->addOr($qb->expr()->field('creator.id')->in($ids))
            ->addOr($qb->expr()->field('modifier.id')->in($ids))
            ->addOr($qb->expr()->field('publisher.id')->in($ids));

    $query = $qb->getQuery();
    $results = $query->execute();

    return $results;
}
```

Where **creator, modifier and publisher can be differents user**.

I'm following this example of Symfony doc: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/testing/database.html#mocking-the-repository-in-a-unit-test

How to test this query builder?. My code look like this:

```
public function testFindArticlesByUsers()
{
    $article = $this->getMock('\Acme\DemoBundle\Document\Article');
    $article->expects($this->once())
        ->method('getCreator')
        ->will($this->returnValue($this->getMock('\Acme\DemoBundle\Document\\User')));
    $article->expects($this->once())
        ->method('getModifier')
        ->will($this->returnValue($this->getMock('\Acme\DemoBundle\Document\\User')));
    $article->expects($this->once())
        ->method('getPublisher')
        ->will($this->returnValue($this->getMock('\Acme\DemoBundle\Document\\User')));

    $articleRepository = $this->getMockBuilder('\Doctrine\ODM\DocumentRepository')
        ->setMethods(array('findArticlesByUsers'))
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();
    $articleRepository->expects($this->once())
        ->method('findArticlesByUsers')
        ->will($this->returnValue($article));

    $documentManager = $this->getMockBuilder('\Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager')
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();
    $documentManager->expects($this->once())
        ->method('getRepository')
        ->will($this->returnValue($articleRepository));

    $article2 = $documentManager->getRepository('BackendBundle:Article')
        ->findArticlesByUsers(1);
}
```

I haven't idea continuous with it and if this is the correct way. The error is:

```
Expectation failed for method name is equal to <string:getCreator> when invoked 1 time(s).
Method was expected to be called 1 times, actually called 0 times.
```

But I'm not sure how to test this and check the result.

**Update:**

I changed the code to pass the test(ok, it's green) but for me this test doesn't work fine because although delete findArticlesByUsers method the test is green. What I'm doing wrong?

```
public function testFindArticlesByUsers()
{
    $userCreator = $this->getMock('\TT\BackendBundle\Document\User');
    $userCreator->expects($this->any())
        ->method('getId')
        ->will($this->returnValue(1));

    $userModifier = $this->getMock('\TT\BackendBundle\Document\User');
    $userModifier->expects($this->any())
        ->method('getId')
        ->will($this->returnValue(2));

    $userPublisher = $this->getMock('\TT\BackendBundle\Document\User');
    $userPublisher->expects($this->any())
        ->method('getId')
        ->will($this->returnValue(3));

    //Article mock
    $article = $this->getMock('\TT\BackendBundle\Document\Article');
    $article->expects($this->once())
        ->method('getCreator')
        ->will($this->returnValue($userCreator));
    $article->expects($this->once())
        ->method('getModifier')
        ->will($this->returnValue($userModifier));
    $article->expects($this->once())
        ->method('getPublisher')
        ->will($this->returnValue($userPublisher));

    $articleRepository = $this->getMockBuilder('\Doctrine\ODM\DocumentRepository')
        ->setMethods(array('findArticlesByUsers'))
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();
    $articleRepository->expects($this->once())
        ->method('findArticlesByUsers')
        ->will($this->returnValue($article));

    $documentManager = $this->getMockBuilder('\Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager')
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();
    $documentManager->expects($this->once())
        ->method('getRepository')
        ->will($this->returnValue($articleRepository));

    $article = $documentManager->getRepository('BackendBundle:Article')
        ->findArticlesByUsers(1);

    $this->assertEquals(1, $article->getCreator()->getId());
    $this->assertEquals(2, $article->getModifier()->getId());
    $this->assertEquals(3, $article->getPublisher()->getId());
}
```

**Update2:**

I think finally I understand mock object :) so doing as above I'm mocking the repository but this isn't the objetive. My last code to test this method is:

```
public function testFindArticlesByUsers()
{
    $userId = $this->dm->createQueryBuilder('AcmeBundle:User')
                              ->field('username')->equals('fakeUser')
                              ->getQuery()->getSingleResult()->getId();

    $articles = $this->dm->getRepository('AcmeBundle:Article')
        ->findArticlesByUsers(array($userId));

    $this->assertGreaterThanOrEqual(1, count($articles));
}
```

The test works although it depends on of it the user exists and has articles. Is ok the test?

Comment: Did you finally found a solution ?

Comment: If your tests depends on the existence of a certain data set, either remove that requirement from your test, or make sure to create the required data in the setup part of your unit test, that way you can make sure it's always present when running the test.